# how to send email as well as display it out

Tags: shell-script, email

I am trying to run a script with the output to be emailed and watched (monitored), I try using this code:

```
    this are the output: >emailmessage
    echo "output here" >>emailmessage
    /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $emailmessage
```

and an email will be sent with the results but won't be displayed on my terminal, for now I use `echo "email sent!"` so I can be notified that the script was done running. How can I send it out and display it as well?

Comment: Why don't you just put the `echo "email sent"` at the bottom of your script?  If you need to make sure it ran OK, you can do `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "email sent"; fi`   Or are you looking for something which will pop something up on your screen?

Comment: Did you try `tee[1]` command? [1] http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee

Comment: @mark, that's what i did earlier so i could be notified that the email was sent out,, @alex -- i need to learn the tee command very quick as well. thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your script is running with a controlling terminal (so that the output has somewhere to go to be seen) you just need to add one line:

```
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $emailmessage
cat $emailmessage
```

Comment: thanks, this is pretty simple and yet i aint aware i could do that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "To: $EMAIL"
echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
echo ""
echo "$emailmessage" | tee >(/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL")
echo "sent!"
```

This uses process substitution, so I've assumed you're using bash or ksh (or similar, check your shell's man page)